# Python - object has no attribute Error

Tags: python, object, attributes, field

**I re-wrote the entire class from scratch in a separate file and everything magically worked, conditionals and all. So, I simply imported that class and a couple functions from the new file into the master file. I still have no idea what went wrong the first time around.**

**Note the issues below were *technically* solved. You can see a typo towards the bottom of the code. That, however, uncovered an issue where all of my conditionals (if, try, etc.) stopped functioning, which is why I re-wrote the class in a separate module**

**I *would* delete this post since it got everyone nowhere, but that's not how things work on Stack Overflow, apparently.**

Alright, I've been learning Python 3.4 and decided to do some homework on the side as practice. I started making a script that does a very basic simulation of 2 people fighting, and would expand upon it with any new stuff I learn (such as adding a GUI).

The script started out fine, but the more changes I made the more errors started showing up. Now it's to the point where I can't access any fields of the "fighter" class without it throwing errors such as:

```
'duelist' object has no attribute '_duelist__health'
```

Besides "*'duelist' object has no attribute '_duelist__XXX'*", I've had 0 other errors besides typos.
Google unfortunately couldn't help with this one, so that's why I'm making my first StackOverflow post.

Here's the class down to the first error-happy field, "health":

```
class duelist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Duelist" #must not be ""
        self.health = 5 #must be >0
        self.damage = [1, 3] #random attack range. Must be >=0 0 and the first must not be higher.
        self.skill = 10 #% chance to pass a skill check. Representative of parrying/dodging. Must be >=0
        self.shield = True #can block?
        self.shieldE = 80 #max block %. Must be >0
        self.agility = 0.5 #rate of attack in seconds. Must be >=0.05
        self.precision = 10 #critical hit chance. Must be >=0
        self.critical = 2.0 #critical multiplier. Must be >= 1.1


    #name
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        if value != "":
            self.__name = value
        else:
            print("Invalid Name.\n")
    #name

    #health
    @property
    def health(self):
        return self.__health

    @health.setter
    def health(self, value):
        try:
            value = value(int)
            if value>=1:
                self.__health = value
            else:
                print("Health must be above 0.\n")
        except:
            print("Invalid Health.\n")
    #health
```

Also, for those suggesting to change the field names to not include an ' __ ' (or to include an ' __ ' everywhere), that causes an infinite loop.
Typing exactly this:

```
class duelist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 5

    @property
    def health(self):
        return self.__health

    @health.setter
    def health(self, value):
        self.__health = value

D = duelist()
print(D.health)
D.health = 15
print(D.health)
```

Correctly returns

```
5
15
```

Comment: You should not access the `health` attribute as `self.__health`. Use `self.health` instead. By the look of your code, you should change the way to access `name` as well.

Comment: Please correct your indentation. Additionally, please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. We are not going to scan through your entire code for you.

Comment: Can you post code that exhibits the problem? I can not replicate the problem with the code posted in your question. Also, are you certain that you are using Python 3? If using Python 2 you must derive your class from `object` in order for properties to work correctly.

Comment: A possible explanation is the mix of tab and spaces in the file, which cannot be seen in this post. Use `python -tt file.py`

Answer (score 3):

Your code does:

1. Set the value of `.name =` inside `__init__()`
2. That goes through the setter, and sets `.__name =`
3. When you read it by `.name` that reads through the getter, and reads `.__name`

And your description of the problem "*I can't access any fields of the "fighter" class*", I suspect is wrong, because accessing *some* of them work.

Health doesn't, though, and on line 45 you have this:

```
value = value(int)
```

instead of

```
value = int(value)
```

So that causes the getter to throw an exception and `print("Invalid Health.\n")` and `__health` is never set.

With `self.shield = True`, the setter is trying to do:

```
if value.lower() == 'y':
```

and you can't call `lower()` on a boolean, so it crashes out before it ever gets to try to `type(value) == bool`, and `__shield` is never set.

Answer (score 1):

The exception *can* be caused if your class does not define an attribute `__health` in its `__init__()` method. Trying to read its value will trigger the problem. The attribute will be created by calling the setter method (indirectly through attribute assignment), and after that the attribute becomes available.

Here is a simplified version of your class:

```
class Duelist:
    def __init__(self):
#        self.health = 5
        pass

    @property
    def health(self):
        return self.__health

    @health.setter
    def health(self, value):
        self.__health = value

>>> d = Duelist()
>>> d.health
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "p.py", line 9, in health
    return self.__health
AttributeError: 'Duelist' object has no attribute '_Duelist__health'
>>> d.health = 123
>>> d.health
123
```

So one way to fix it is to initialise the attributes using the *same* name:

```
class Duelist:
    def __init__(self):
#        self.health = 5    # this will also work
        self.__health = 5

>>> d.health
5
>>> d.health = 123
>>> d.health
123
```

So, given that the exception will be raised if you do not initialise the property (`self.health`) or the underlying attribute (`self.__health`), have you posted the actual code that causes the problem in your question?

Comment: @FierySwordswoman: sorry, my mistake, the code I've posted does not raise the exception that I've shown. The code that does raise that exception omits the `__init__()` method. That's the only way that I have been able to replicate your problem.

Comment: @FierySwordswoman: I've updated my code with that which causes the problem.

Comment: @FierySwordswoman: I think that [`TessellatingHeckler's answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39553785/21945) explains why the attribute is not being set in `__init__()`. What problem do you now have?